# Linux command to check VM is azure VM or amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, azure

Is there any linux command to check VM is azure VM or amazon EC2 instance ? If there help me on this .

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve (curl) the Instance Metadata URL: `169.254.169.254`

Both AWS and Azure use it, but they return different information.